# OSGI. Waiting for timeout during installation of bundle (tinybundles)

Tags: osgi, karaf, pax-exam

I have a  problem running pax exam test under karaf.
During an installation of bundle

```
2015-05-20 14:16:42,644 | DEBUG | FelixStartLevel  | BundleManager                    | 1 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.0 | Checking file:/tmp/ops4j-store-anonymous-568188393605841387/tinybundles_c3beb06a2df3da75e08a1ae1a44c832cfbd034c0.bin
```

it hangs for some time in

```
org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BundleManager#waitForUrlHandler
```

looking for a

```
(&(objectClass=org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService)(url.handler.protocol=file))
```

here is the thread dump:

```
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.waitForService(ServiceTracker.java:499)
  at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BundleManager.waitForUrlHandler(BundleManager.java:229)
  at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BundleManager.getInputStreamForBundle(BundleManager.java:186)
  at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BundleManager.doInstallBundleIfNeeded(BundleManager.java:99)
  at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BundleManager.installBundleIfNeeded(BundleManager.java:90)
  at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.doInstallFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:523)
  at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:383)
  at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BootFeaturesInstaller.installBootFeatures(BootFeaturesInstaller.java:92)
  at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BootFeaturesInstaller.start(BootFeaturesInstaller.java:76)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:297)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:958)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:712)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:824)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:681)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:378)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)
  - locked <0xbb5> (a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:276)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:245)
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:235)
  at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)
  at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)
  at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)
  at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)
  at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1103)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:695)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:483)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4403)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2092)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1291)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I didn't find any bundle that provides that service => so my test hangs for 30sec each time installing tinybundle's folder.

I've started a paxexam's karaf manually from the target folder and I ran service:list to see what bundles can provide URLStreamHandlerService service but there wasn't any with url.handler.protocol=file

```
service.id = 2
Provided by : 
 System Bundle (0)
Used by: 
 Apache Felix File Install (17)
 Apache Aries JMX Core (225)

[org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService]

 service.id = 51
 url.handler.protocol = feature
Provided by : 
 Apache Karaf :: Deployer :: Features (12)

[org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService]

 service.id = 15
 url.handler.protocol = jardir
Provided by : 
 Apache Felix File Install (17)

[org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService]

 service.id = 42
 url.handler.protocol = spring
Provided by : 
 Apache Karaf :: Deployer :: Spring (27)

[org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService]

service.id = 45
 url.handler.protocol = blueprint
Provided by : 
 Apache Karaf :: Deployer :: Blueprint (30)

[org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService]

 service.id = 4
 url.handler.protocol = [wrap]
Provided by : 
 OPS4J Pax Url - wrap: (37)

[org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService]
```

So the question is: how can I avoid waiting for a timeout. Do we really need URLStreamHandlerService service, if yes how can I provide it ?

Comment: I would call this a bug in Karaf. There's no way they should be doing a blocking wait for a service during a synchronous bundle event callback. That's a newbie mistake.

Comment: It's not a bundle event. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-3730.

Comment: @hwellmann It certainly is a bundle event... see near the bottom of the stack trace: `fireBundleEvent`. The fact that it's blocking in an EventHook rather than an ordinary BundleListener is nitpicking. Anyway, I'm glad to see this is recognized as a bug in Karaf.